# I am using LeafletJS and JavaScript to display points on a MapBox map. The points are not lining up though. They are close but not exact

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I am using LeafletJS to display points on a MapBox map.  The points are not lining up though.  They are close but not exact.

I have my setView set to the following location:

var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([40.311420, -75.134643], 17);

Then I am trying to plot a point at 40.310676, -75.138090 by doing this:

```
    temp.LatLng = new L.LatLng(40.310653, -75.138070);

    g.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", temp.LatLng.lat)
        .attr("cy", temp.LatLng.lng)
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("fill", "#ffff00")
        .attr("stroke", "#ffff00")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + mymap.latLngToLayerPoint(temp.LatLng).x + "," + mymap.latLngToLayerPoint(temp.LatLng).y + ")");
```

As you can see in the image below the point (in yellow) does show up but it is not in the correct location.  It should be where the red dot is.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv93X.jpg)

Thank you in advance for any help you might be able to supply.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up answering my own question.

In the code where i am drawing the circles I was setting the cx and cy to the latitude and longitude and then transforming them from there. Like this:

```
   g.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", temp.LatLng.lat)
        .attr("cy", temp.LatLng.lng)
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("fill", "#ffff00")
        .attr("stroke", "#ffff00")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + mymap.latLngToLayerPoint(temp.LatLng).x + "," + mymap.latLngToLayerPoint(temp.LatLng).y + ")");
```

What I should have been doing is drawing the original circle at 0,0 and transforming them from there. This is what the coded ended up looking like:

```
   g.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", 0)
        .attr("cy", 0)
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("fill", "#ffff00")
        .attr("stroke", "#ffff00")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + mymap.latLngToLayerPoint(temp.LatLng).x + "," + mymap.latLngToLayerPoint(temp.LatLng).y + ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `L.Circle` or `L.CircleMarker`. This will let Leaflet deal with the specific details of positioning SVG geometries in the DOM.